Solving $\lim_{x\to \infty}=\frac{x\sqrt{x+1}(1-\sqrt{2x+3})}{7-6x+4x^2}$
The problem:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}=\frac{x\sqrt{x+1}(1-\sqrt{2x+3})}{7-6x+4x^2}$$
The solution:
$-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$
How I have started:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}=\frac{x\sqrt{x+1}(1-\sqrt{2x+3})}{7-6x+4x^2}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^2\cdot\frac{1}{x}\cdot \sqrt{x+1}\cdot(1-\sqrt{2x+3})}{x^2(4-\frac{6}{x}+\frac{7}{x^2})}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x}\cdot \sqrt{x+1}\cdot(1-\sqrt{2x+3})}{4-\frac{6}{x}+\frac{7}{x^2}}$$
My question:
I'm stuck. How do I continue on from here to reach the solution?

As $x\to\infty$, $$4-\frac{6}{x}+\frac{7}{x^2}\to4,$$ and $$\frac1x\sqrt{x+1}(1-\sqrt{2x+3})=\sqrt{1+\frac1x}\left(\frac1{\sqrt x}-\sqrt{2+\frac3x}\right)\to1\cdot(0-\sqrt2)=-\sqrt2.$$

The limit of the denominator is $4$. For the numerator:
$$\frac1x\sqrt{x+1}(1-\sqrt{2x+3})=\sqrt{\frac1x+\frac1x^2}-\sqrt{\frac{(x+1)(2x+3)}{x^2}}\\=\sqrt{\frac1x+\frac1x^2}-\sqrt{2+\frac5x+\frac3{x^2}}$$
The limit of the first term is $0$, the limit of the second is $\sqrt 2$.

Using the asymptotic analysis, $x\sqrt{x+1}\sim x\sqrt x$, $1-\sqrt{2x+3}\sim -\sqrt{2x}$ so the numerator behaves like $\sqrt{2}x^2$. In the denominator, the leading term is $4x^2$, hence the limit is $-\sqrt 2/4$.
